# Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

int main() {

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int x=1;
    int *numOfPhases=&x;
    char** nameOfPhases=malloc((*numOfPhases)*sizeof(*nameOfPhases));
    char* stTemp;
    //TODO: check if NULL
    for (i=0; i<(*numOfPhases);i++) {
        nameOfPhases[i]=malloc(sizeof(char));
        char *st=nameOfPhases[i];
        printf("enter char\n");
        do {
            stTemp=malloc(st,sizeof(char)*(j+1));
            //TODO: check if NULL
            st[j]=getchar();
            j++;
        } while (st[j]!='\n');
        if (j>=1) {
            st[j-1]='\0';
        }
        st[j]=0;
        printf("%s \n", nameOfPhases[i]);
        j=0;
    }

    for (i=0;i<(*numOfPhases);i++) {
        printf("%s ", nameOfPhases[i]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<(*numOfPhases);i++) {
        free(nameOfPhases[i]);
    }

    free(nameOfPhases);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on Windows, everything works just fine. However, when I run this on Unix via [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) I encounter a few errors such as:

```
==10215== Invalid read of size 1
==10215==    at 0x343F047E2C: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==10215==    by 0x343F0495DF: buffered_vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==10215==    by 0x343F04421D: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==10215==    by 0x343F04F189: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==10215==    by 0x400837: main 
==10215==  Address 0x4c23090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==10215==    at 0x4A06C20: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:662)
==10215==    by 0x4007CC: main 
==10215== 
==10215== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==10215==    at 0x4A06430: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==10215==    by 0x4008AF: main 
==10215==  Address 0x4c23090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==10215==    at 0x4A06C20: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:662)
==10215==    by 0x4007CC: main 
==10215== 
==10215== 
==10215== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10215==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==10215==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 12 bytes allocated
==10215== 
==10215== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==10215==    at 0x4A06C20: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:662)
==10215==    by 0x4007CC: main (in /homet2/ayeletk/OG/main.exe)
==10215== 
==10215== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10215==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==10215==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10215==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10215==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10215==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10215== 
==10215== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10215== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could happen?

Comment: your allocations are all wrong. A miracle it works on windows. First, `int x=1;
    int *numOfPhases=&x;` what's the use?? then ... well you should rewrite your code you've got memory leaks / too short allocations all along. Did you read the compilation warnings? Oh another one: `stTemp=malloc(st,sizeof(char)*(j+1));` and you never use `stTemp` again

Comment: I would recommend that you read a  [link: C Programming Language book](https://hassanolity.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf). Learn to allocate memory properly

Comment: You only malloc a single `char` for `nameOfPhases[i]`. You malloc an array of `char` for `stTemp`, but never use it or free it. `st` points to the same single `char` as `nameOfPhases[i]` and the accesses to `st[j]` are invalid when  `j` > 0.

Answer (score 1):

here are some, but not all the problems in the code:

1. 'numOfPhases is never changed after being initialized and always points to 'x'so can simplify by always using 'x' instead of '*numOfPhases'
2. when the above problem is incorporated, then can eliminate variable 'numOfPhases'
3. 'sizeof(char)' is defined in the standard as 1, for clarity use 1
4. nothing in the posted code uses 'false' nor 'true' nor 'bool' so the statement `#include <stdbool.h>` should be removed
5. none of the output statements are missing a trailing '\n' so the statements `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` and `setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` have no effect, other than to clutter the code
6. the variable 'x' is initialized to 1 then never changed.  suggest using a '#define' rather than a variable
7. this statement is invalid as 'malloc()' only has a single parameter `stTemp=malloc(st,sizeof(char)*(j+1));`
8. the array 'st[]' is not defined in the posted code so any references to 'st' will cause the compiler to output an error message
9. for ease of readability and understanding of the code, separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line
10. multiplying any value by 1 makes no difference and just clutters the code, so do not be multiplying by `sizeof(char)`

there are plenty of other problems in the code but this should get you started in the right direction.

Note: always enable all the compiler warnings, then fix those warnings.

for 'gcc', at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`